UBUNTU on Macbook Pro 2017 sound not working
I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 in a partition in my MacBook Pro and my speakers, and microphone do not work. I am new to Ubuntu and I am looking everywhere to know how to fix it, but I do not know how to fix it.
The only way I can make it work is by connecting it to another screen with speakers via HDMI.
Specs:
  Model Name: MacBook Pro Model
  Identifier: MacBookPro14,1
  Processor Name: Dual-Core Intel Core i5
  Processor Speed: 2,3 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 2
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 4 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
  Memory: 8 GB
  System Firmware Version: 529.140.2.0.0
  OS Loader Version: 577.140.2~22
  SMC Version (system): 2.43f11
  Serial Number (system): C02VFGRDHV29
  Hardware UUID: C2BE82E0-D5C1-5DDE-8468-8D770AD959FB
  Provisioning UDID: C2BE82E0-D5C1-5DDE-8468-8D770AD959FB
 FaceTime HD Camera:
  Model ID: Apple Camera
  VendorID_0x106B
  ProductID_0x1570
  Unique ID: CC27343YC93GJJM13
Devices
Built-in Microphone:
  Default Input Device: Yes
  Input Channels: 2
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Current SampleRate: 44100
  Transport: Built-in
  Input Source: Internal Microphone
Built-in Output:
  Default Output Device: Yes
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Output Channels: 2
  Current SampleRate: 44100
  Transport: Built-in
  Output Source: Internal Speakers
DisplayPort:
  Default System Output Device: Yes
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Output Channels: 2
  Current SampleRate: 48000
  Transport: DisplayPort
  Output Source: LG TV
Dolby Audio Bridge:
  Input Channels: 130
  Manufacturer: Dolby Laboratories
  Output Channels: 130
  Current SampleRate: 44100
  Transport: Unknown
  Input Source: Default
  Output Source: Default
ZoomAudioDevice:
  Input Channels: 2
  Manufacturer: zoom.us
  Output Channels: 2
  Current SampleRate: 48000
  Transport: Virtual
  Input Source: Default
  Output Source: Default
I have read many things, but I am not sure what to do.

I followed this to get bluetooth working just today: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/hya1m8/macbook_13_inch_2017_bluetooth_not_working_in/
Edit: From following others I found that this is what got my audio working - https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409
For webcam this worked for me - https://victorleungtw.medium.com/install-ubuntu-20-04-lts-on-macbookpro14-1-9f1b6afde43d
Previously posted:
For sound... I got it working, but I am not sure what I did to get it to work. Do install BT before sound though, as in my case I was trying to get sound working first but no matter what I did it didnt work... but once I had BT working sound worked.
Honestly these are links that I followed... I am really not sure which one worked so I am including all the links
Bluetooth not working on a MacBook Pro 2017
https://aaroalhainen.medium.com/how-i-fixed-my-ubuntu-20-04-no-audio-dummy-output-issue-eaa525838e0d
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=392586&hilit=cs8409
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_on_mac/comments/1cpa2jt/no_sound_on_macbook_pro_help/
https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro
Also check my answer here Macbook Pro 14,1 Issues (all noticed so far)
